# Extracting character sequence containing word

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I've got an HTML string containing special character sequences looking like this:

```
[start_tag attr="value"][/end_tag]
```

I want to be able to extract one of these sequences containing specific attribute e.g:

```
[my_image_tag image_id="12345" attr2="..." ...]
```

and from the above example, I want to extract the whole thing with square brackets but using only one of the attributes and its value in this case - `image_id="12345"`

I tried using regex but it gives me the whole line whereas I need only the part of the line based on specific value as mentioned above.

Comment: Can text be included between [start_tag][/end_tag]? If yes, does that mean that you could embed a tag in another tag? What do you really want to extract? The whole thing "[start_tag] Maybe some text [/end_tag]"? Could you clarify?

Comment: How did you end up with HTML but not HTML? These tags are going to be just as hard as HTML to parse, but you don't get to use an HTML parser to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
my_string = '<h1>Heading1</h1>some text soem tex some text [some_tag attrs][/some_tag]some text some text [some_tag image_id="12345"] some text'

search_attrs = %w(image_id foo bar)

found = my_string =~ /(\[[^\]]*(#{search_attrs.join('|')})="[^"\]]*"[^\]]*\])/ && $1
# => "[some_tag image_id=\"12345\"]"
```

For a specific attribute id and value, you can simplify it like so:

```
found = my_string =~ /(\[[^\]]* image_id="12345"[^\]]*\])/ && $1
# => "[some_tag image_id=\"12345\"]"
```

It works by expanding the primary capture group to everything you're looking for.

However, this assumes you only need to extract one such attribute.

It also assumes that you don't care if the string crosses through any HTML tag boundaries.  If you cared about that, then you'd need to first hash out the legal boundaries using an HTML parser, then search within those results.

Comment: oh by default the string doesn't cross through HTML as I mentioned it earlier the actula string looks something like this:
"<h1>Heading1</h1>some text soem tex some text [some_tag attrs][/some_tag]some text some text [some_tag image_id="12345"] some text"

This should make it clearer

Comment: It only returns the attribute but I need the whole thing I mean the attribute with the entire tag like this: "[some_tag image_id="12345"] " - this is what I need

Comment: Thanks I lot this works but I can't seem to get it right for both attribute and value e.g when I want to get the specific tag for attribute image_id with 12345 not just any id value.

Comment: @Gregg I added an example using that id-value pair